# Missing value on JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

The code is created as follow:

```
function create_story_json_file()
{
//Update the last edited page:

    img_dataURLs[current_page]= drawing_plate.toDataURL("image/png");
    create_display_img_url(current_page);

    var page_num= total_page_num;                               //Story total page number
    var page_cont= new Array();
    var page_view= new Array();

    //Page View:( as the pages is clicked, the page views have to be shown. 
        page_view= display_img_dataURL;


    var img_data_URL;           //if it's a variable only, you have to assign the first value in the declaration, or the tag would disappear. 
    var stamp_arr= new Array();
    var rec_arr= new Array();
    var background_msc; 


//For each Story:   
    alert("total_page_num :"+ total_page_num );
    for(var p_number=0 ; p_number < total_page_num ; p_number++)
    {
        img_data_URL= img_dataURLs[p_number];

    //Stamp
        stamp_arr= [];                                          //reset.    
        var stamp_arr_for_current_page= stamp_for_all_pages[ p_number ].arr;
        for(var stamp_num= 0; stamp_num < stamp_arr_for_current_page.length ; stamp_num++)
        {
            stamp_arr.push( stamp_arr_for_current_page[stamp_num].get_stmp_json_obj );

        }
        alert("stamp_arr.length is:" + stamp_arr.length);
    //Rec:
        rec_arr= [];
        var rec_objs_at_certain_page= records_pages_arr[ p_number ].rec_objs;
        for(var rec_num= 0; rec_num <  rec_objs_at_certain_page.length; rec_num++)
        {
            rec_arr.push( rec_objs_at_certain_page[ rec_num ].get_rec_json_obj );               //check if rec_objs_at_certain_page[ rec_num ] is a rec_object! 
        }
        alert("rec_arr length is: " + rec_arr.length);
    //Background_music:
        var bgr_msc_in_certain_page= back_ground_music_arr[ p_number ];
        alert ("bgr_msc_in_certain_page.created" + bgr_msc_in_certain_page.created);
        background_msc= bgr_msc_in_certain_page.get_bgr_msc_json_obj;





        var page_content_json_obj= {
            img_data_url: img_data_URL,
            stamp:stamp_arr,
            record: rec_arr,
            bgr_msc:  background_msc
        }

        page_cont.push(page_content_json_obj); 


    }


        var story_json_obj= {

        page_number: page_num, 
        page_content: page_cont,
                    page_img_view: page_view

        }

    //Change to JSON String and write it to the file.   
    story_json_str= JSON.stringify(story_json_obj);
}
```

I am confused about that why the result JSON string: **story_json_str** would be:

```
{"page_number":1,
"page_content":[{"img_data_url":"data:image/base64......lots of      character"}]}
```

And nothing else, where are "stamp" ,"record" and "bgr_msc" in "page_content"? 
And why does "page_img_view" disappear too?
Why do they miss?

**Please explain and correct the code.**

Ps: I work on Android System, storing the JSON string to a file by the feature of HTML5. I don't have debug platform to use...

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have a debug platform"? Do the alerts work?

Comment: Yes. But what I mean is that I want a debugger like Firebug || Chromium developer tools. ( developed on mobile system)
Btw: I have a question: JSON={key: value}. If the value is undefined, will it cause the creation of JSON  object fail?

Comment: No, it won't fail, but the property will not be included - `undefined` is no legal value in JSON. If you need to represent a missing value, you might use `null` instead

Comment: But I find if the `value` is `undefined`, the `key`("key":"value") will disappear.

Comment: you might want to try firebug lite https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: @Stallman: That's what I've said. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description

Comment: @Bergi         Thanks, I will study hard to figure out what actually happen to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fault eventually.

```
background_msc= bgr_msc_in_certain_page.get_bgr_msc_json_obj;
```

Since `get_bgr_msc_json_obj` is a function in a class, I need to write
`get_bgr_msc_json_obj()`. Missing the parentheses won't call the function.

 
These two instruments: `get_rec_json_obj` and `get_stmp_json_obj` make the same mistake. 
What a stupid mistake.